# Regex that matches values currency decimal input

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will allow any number greater than 0, with or without a decimal, and allows either one or two decimal places.

I found the following `\d+\.?\d{1,2}` which works for everything except 0-9.

What's wrong? I'm under the impression the `\d+` is supposed to represent anything with [0-9] characters that is 1 or more digits long.

Comment: \d+ requires 1 digit and \d{1,2} requires one or two digits. Since the decimal point is optional, the minimum number of digits for a integer matched by the regex is 2. Try something like this: \d+(\.\d{1,2})?

Comment: This isn't exactly correct but got me on the right path. The problem was I was always expecting at least two decimal characters. `\d+` required one and then `\d{1,2}` required either one or two.  The solution was simple. `\d+\.?\d{0,2}`

Comment: @sanpaco - Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the solution to my problem after reading some of the comments.  I was requiring at least two decimal characters in my regex.

Its easiest to explain by breaking the regex down into three sections.

1. The first section is anything I want to allow before the decimal
   point and is represented by `\d+`. This pattern tells me to allow
   any [0-9] character and there must be 1 or more characters.
2. The next section is the decimal point which is optional and is
   represented by `\.?`.
3. The final section is where the problem was.  I had `\d{1,2}`. This
   pattern says to require 1 or 2 decimal characters [0-9]. Since I
   wanted to have the decimal place numbers be optional the correct
   pattern for this should be `\d{0,2}` which says that I can have 0,
   1, or 2 decimal characters [0-9]. Since the first section requires at least one character and the third section was requiring 1 or 2, I was requiring at least 2 characters in my entire regex pattern and thus, anything with only one character (ie 0-9) was invalid.

The updated pattern is `\d+\.?\d{0,2}` and correctly allows all the values I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work -

```
 # [1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?

 [1-9] \d*                     # any number greater than 0
 (?: \. \d{0,2} )?             # with or without a decimal and/or 1 or two places
```